# Mirror Git Repository

Tags: git, apache, ubuntu

I have done some research but can't find the answer that I need.

Basically, I am planning to clone from an existing Git repository such as Apache and I want this Git repository to be synchronised all the time. This will be on 1 machine (Ubuntu).

Now, I want to pull changes from this Ubuntu machine to my local desktop machine. Make changes and push back to the Ununtu machine.

Next the Ununtu machine, should push changes that were made to the original Git repository (Apache).

How is it possible to mirror this? What steps I will need to take? Would you have some examples?

I have tried `git clone --mirror URL`. From what I understand this would clone the repository and mirror.

For the Ubuntu machine, I setup a new Git repository by using `git init`. For the above command `git clone --mirror URL` I put the URL of the `git init'.

How would I automatically keep sync the machines? I think `git push --mirror URL`?

Thanks.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to work like this?

Comment: So that developers don't need to know which repository is behind the scenes. In addition, so that commits/pushes can be faster. Also, in case I would like a proxy server in the future I don't need to make much changes

Comment: Do you have Apache git commit rights?

Comment: Yes my friend I do. Can you help me please?

Comment: Commit/pushes are rare enough that this is not a reason. At your current level of git knowledge I would recommend against doing this. Too many moving parts and magic. Just use github until you know it better.